# Under what conditions can we write $F(x,y) = 0$ for some function $F$ if we have given functions $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ defined on the interval $[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, partial-differential-equations

While checking the existence of the general solution $F(u,v)=0$ for a quasi linear first order PDE: $$P(x,y,u)u_x+Q(x,y,u)u_y=R(x,y,u),$$ through the characteristic system $$\frac{dx}{dt}=P,~\frac{dy}{dt}=Q,~\text{and}~\frac{du}{dt}=R,$$I had a doubt,

Suppose we have two smooth functions $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ defined on the time interval $[a,b]$, and we want to know under what conditions it is possible to express an equation in terms of $x$ and $y$, i.e., find a smooth function $F(x,y)$ such that $F(x(t),y(t)) = 0$ for all values of $t$.

Even though I got such $F$ in most cases, I have struggled with $x(t)=\sin t$ and $y(t)=\sin t \cos t$.

In general, under what conditions can we write $F(x,y) = 0$ for some function $F$? Is there a general criterion that determines whether such a function $F$ exists? If so, what is it?

Conversely, are there cases where it is impossible to express an equation in terms of two given functions $x$ and $y$? If so, what are the conditions under which this occurs?

Any insights or references to relevant literature would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It seems you need some more restrictions on $F$.  Starting with "$F$ is not identically zero" but even that isn't enough.  Where did this problem come from?

Comment: Coincidentally, for your example of $x(t) = \sin t$ and $y(t) = \sin t \cos t$, we have $x^2 - x^4 - y^2 = 0$.  My guess is this satisfies your criterion, but I'm not even positive about that.

Comment: @BrianMoehring thanks for asking me to indicate the scenario.

Comment: @TeM I am not clear about ''If it's possible to return to a polynomial system'', what exactly does it mean? Can you specify in the context of $x(t)=\sin t,~y(t)=\sin t \cos t$? thanks in advance.